# SpriteKit Game Center Authentication

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I am doing a sprite kit Game. I have a problem with Game Center: how i authenticate player?
in AppDelegate.swift i have this code:

```
     func authenticateLocalPlayer()
     {


     var localPlayer = getLocalPlayer() // see GKLocalPlayerHack.h
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
        {(viewController : NSViewController?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if viewController != nil
            {
                self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated:true, completion: nil)

                        }
```

but i get this error:

```
Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'presentViewController'
```

on this line:

```
 self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: you are using self.presentViewController at wrong place self.presentViewController function relative to    UIViewController so write your function inside a    UIViewController

Comment: The problem is that i have not a UIViewController...i have a SpriteKit Game without view Controllers....i need only to authenticate Player with Game Center at startup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use something like this. I am not 100% sure what you set for the parentWindow bit, my OSX knowledge is limited.

```
let dialogController = GKDialogController.shared()
dialogController.parentWindow = yourWindow // not exactly sure what you need to set here
dialogController.presentViewController(viewController)
```

[Implementing GameKit.framework on OSX, cannot authenticate localPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862161/implementing-gamekit-framework-on-osx-cannot-authenticate-localplayer)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/DisplayingGameCenterUserInterfaceElements/DisplayingGameCenterUserInterfaceElements.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a sprite kit game without view controllers...i need only player authentication with Game Center...i need that a window appears from sprite kit and let my player login to Game Center service...it's possible to do that?

Comment: I used your code but now i get that warning in console    'Could not get services from gamed. Please file a radar including GameKit logs, and any gamed crash logs'     the game runs perfectly but no game center authentication...

Comment: i also get that warning:The connection to service named com.apple.gamed.osx was invalidated.

Comment: Sorry, I was basing my answer on the link I posted. My knowledge about OSX is next to nothing.

Comment: Thank you, i upgraded to Xcode 8 and converted my code to Swift 3.0 syntax...now authentication work!

Comment: I have a new problem with your code. If "Game Center login screen" appear on screen and i click "cancel button" , it opens automatically another window, with another instance of my game. I can not figure how to solve this problem. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a viewcontroller ;-)
Take a look at my answer here I won't copy it one to one.

[Adding Game Center Leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691574/adding-game-center-leaderboard)